# using PJSIP library in android, also how to use JNI libraries in NDK

Tags: android, java-native-interface, pjsip

I need to use PJSIP library in my android project. But I do not have more experience in JNI library usage. Anyone please help me for using PJSIP library.

i just look through the CSIPSimple app. But I don't understand the usage of that library.
There is no tutorial found for this on internet yet.

I need a simple one activity example for understanding the use of this library

So anyone kindly help me with a simple code example.....

Comment: As that technology is over five years old I guess you will never get any tutorials for it...

Comment: yes, but now i need to make a simple sip calling app. So please help me how can I use this library..